# Payment: Pay via prepaid card

Tags: java, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

I want to integrate into my website different payment option for example, I want to let customers pay via prepaid card(paypal is already integrated) .

I have two questions:

How to integrate prepaid card payment with jsp?

How can I integrate other payment options easily, like: credit card, debit card, google checkout, payment via amazon?

I really appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the payment provider www.shareit.com for Credit Card Payment. They offer a simple button solution for payment

Regards